# Inserting upper comma into database

Tags: mysql

I have a problem when inserting data into database any word with upper comma. For example if insert `haven’t` it will be inserted in this format `havenâ€™t` BUT if I insert `haven't`  it will be inserted successfully. So the main problem is  this comma `’` . Any help here please.

Comment: Character set / collation troubles!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inserting your data in in a charset that is different from the on your database is using.

To be a bit more specific: you seem to be inserting a variable-width encoded string (e.g. UTF-8) into a fixed-width encoded db (e.g. ISO-8895 family).

Comment: Specifically, it looks like you are inserting variable-width UTF-8 encoded data in to a database with single-byte character set encoding.